# ¿Como puedo comprobar si el botón "submit" de mi form ha sido pulsado? PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente dilema.

Estoy haciendo un Login que le dice al usuario que tiene que llenar ambos campos del formulario en caso de que se halla omitido alguno.

El problema es que mi código se ejecuta ni bien el usuario entra a la página y le aparece dicho mensaje ya que obiamente los campos estarán vacios al comienzo.

Se me ocurrió que entonces debo poner la lógica en base a si el botón "submit" del formulario ha sido pulsado o no, pero no sé como hacer esto en PHP.

Dejo parte de mi código:

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");

$intentos = 0;

if (empty($_POST["usuario"]) || empty($_POST["contrasenia"])) {
    $error = "Debe completar todos los campos del formulario";
}

else {

 $usuario     = $_POST["usuario"];
 $contrasenia = $_POST["contrasenia"];

 if ($resultado = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from Administrador where usuario='" . $usuario . "' and contrasenia='" . $contrasenia . "'")) {

     if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1) {
         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

         if ($row['contrasenia'] == $contrasenia && $row['usuario'] == $usuario) {
             session_start();
             $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
             header("Location: ../html/admin.html");
         }
     } else {
               $error = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta";
               $intentos++; 
     }  
 }
}
?>
```

Y el form:

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<label for="usuario">Nombre de usuario<br />
<input type="text" name="usuario" class="input" size="20" /></label>
</p>
<p>
<label for="contrasenia">Contraseña<br />
<input type="password" name="contrasenia" placeholder="***********" class="input" size="20" /></label>
</p>
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="login" class="button" value="Entrar" />
</p>
</form>
</p><p id="error"><?php echo $error ?></p>
</div>
</div> <!-- Cierra el div del container -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese tipo de validaciones conviene hacerlas del lado del cliente, aunque también valides en el servidor.

Por ejemplo, puedes hacer que, de entrada, tu botón aparezca desactivado y sólo se active cuando la condición requerida se cumpla. De ese modo estableces un control estricto sobre el comportamiento del usuario, el cual nunca podrá enviar el formulario si no está debidamente cumplimentado.

### Del lado del cliente: Javascript

```js
$(function() {
  /*Creamos referencias a los elementos*/
  var $btnEnviar = $("#btnEnviar");
  var $theInputs = $(".input");
  
  /*De entrada desactivamos el botón*/
  $btnEnviar.prop("disabled", true);

  /*Aquí escuchamos los cambios en cada input*/
  $theInputs.on("change paste keyup", function() {
    /*Recorremos los inputs desde validateInputs()*/
    var bolDisabled = validateInputs();

    /*Cambiamos o  no  el estado del botón según el valor de bolDisabled*/
    $btnEnviar.prop("disabled", bolDisabled);

  });

  /*
   *Se ejecutará al hacer clic en el botón
   *aquí pones tu llamada Ajax
   */
  $btnEnviar.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Acciones al presionar el botón");
  });

  /*Función de validación*/
  function validateInputs() {
    var isValid = false;
    $theInputs.each(function() {
      if ($.trim($(this).val()) === '')
        isValid = true;
    });
    return isValid;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="admin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>
    <label for="usuario">Nombre de usuario<br />
<input type="text" name="usuario" class="input" size="20" /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="contrasenia">Contraseña<br />
<input type="password" name="contrasenia" placeholder="***********" class="input" size="20" /></label>
  </p>
  <p class="submit">
    <input id="btnEnviar" type="submit" name="login" class="button" value="Entrar" />
  </p>
</form>
```

---

### Del lado del servidor: PHP

A mi me gusta este estilo, basado en operadores ternarios. Creo que el código queda más elegante:

```
 $usuario     = !(empty($_POST["usuario"]))      ?  $_POST["usuario"]     :  NULL;
 $contrasenia = !(empty($_POST["contrasenia"]))  ?  $_POST["contrasenia"] :  NULL;


 /*Evaluamos ambas variables*/
 if ($usuario && $contrasenia){
     /*Todo OK, lanzamos la consulta*/
 }else{
    $error = "Debe completar todos los campos del formulario";
 }
```

---

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> Tu consulta es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Para
> evitar ese riesgo que podría traer consecuencias catastróficas sobre
> tus datos e incluso sobre tu sistema, considera el uso de consultas
> preparadas.

Answer (score 1):

intenta con:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("conexion.php");

$_SESSION["intentos"] = 0;

if (empty($_POST["usuario"]) || empty($_POST["contrasenia"])) {
    $_SESSION["error"]= "Debe completar todos los campos del formulario";
}

else {

 $usuario     = $_POST["usuario"];
 $contrasenia = $_POST["contrasenia"];

 if ($resultado = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from Administrador where usuario='" . $usuario . "' and contrasenia='" . $contrasenia . "'")) {

     if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1) {
         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

         if ($row['contrasenia'] == $contrasenia && $row['usuario'] == $usuario) {
             //session_start();
             $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
             unset($_SESSION["error"]);
             unset($_SESSION["intentos"]);
             header("Location: ../html/admin.html");
         }
     } else {
               $_SESSION["error"] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta";
               $_SESSION["intentos"]=$_SESSION["intentos"]+1; 
     }  
 }
}
?>
```

y en el html

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<label for="usuario">Nombre de usuario<br />
<input type="text" name="usuario" class="input" size="20" /></label>
</p>
<p>
<label for="contrasenia">Contraseña<br />
<input type="password" name="contrasenia" placeholder="***********" class="input" size="20" /></label>
</p>
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="login" class="button" value="Entrar" />
</p>
</form>
</p><p id="error"><?php echo isset($_SESSION["error"]) ? $_SESSION["error"] : "";?></p>
</div>
</div> <!-- Cierra el div del container -->
```

Comment: la logica está buena, pero me sigue tirando el mismo error con tu codigo

Comment: que tipo de error te arroja!

Comment: Osea, tengo el mismo problema que antes ... cuando entra la primera vez que tira el error de "debe completar todos los campos del formulario" !! Lo que estaría bien si fuese la segunda vez, pero la primera que se entra a la pagina no debería decir nada!

Answer (score 0):

intenta lo siguiente en tu if

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && (empty($_POST["usuario"]) || empty($_POST["contrasenia"]))) {
    $_SESSION["error"]= "Debe completar todos los campos del formulario";
}
```

Comment: Mejora tu respuesta explica tu código